# ko.computed in KnockoutJS to do list app

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I'm making a simple to do list app to learn KnockoutJS. Right now I can add a task, and when I click the 'Remove' link, the task is removed from the view. I have a count of tasks at the bottom that uses a ko.computed function. It updates when I add a task, but when I remove a task the number stays the same. Does anyone know what's wrong with the code below?

Here's my JS:

```
$(function() {
var Todo = function (task, complete) {
    this.task = task;
    this.complete = complete;
}

var AppViewModel = function(todos) {
    var self = this;

    //Create an observable array of Todo objects
    self.toDoItems = ko.observableArray([
        { task: "Learn KnockoutJS", complete: false}
    ]);



    //Add a new todo
    self.add = function() {
        self.toDoItems.push(new Todo($('.txt').val()));
        $('.txt').val('');
    };

    //Remove a todo
    self.remove = function(item) {
        self.toDoItems.destroy(item);
    }

    //Mark a todo complete
    self.complete = function (item) {
        item.complete = true;
    }


    //Count active tasks
    self.remainingTasks = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.toDoItems().length;
    })
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());

});
```

And here's my view:

```
<h3>Tasks</h3>

<table>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: toDoItems">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="click: $root.complete"></td>
      <td class="todo-item"><label data-bind="text: task"></label></td>
      <td class="remove"><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.remove">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 <br>
 <input class="txt" />
 <button data-bind="click: add">Add</button><br><br>
 There are <strong data-bind="text: remainingTasks"></strong> tasks here.<br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

knockout observable arrays implement two ways to delete items: `remove()`, which actually removes the item from the array, and `destroy()`, which just marks the items as "destroyed" but keeps it in the list. So probably `remove()` is what you want, not `destroy()`:

```
self.remove = function(item) {
    self.toDoItems.remove(item);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `.destroy` which doesn't actually remove the item from the array; it only adds a *property* to the object.  This is intended to be a convenience for Rails developers as [noted in the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html).

If you change your code to call `.remove` then the item will be removed from the array.

[Here is a jsFiddle as an example](http://jsfiddle.net/KmB2X/).